# Where to add google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')

Tags: javascript, google-maps

*There are similar questions to this but different code so asking for my specific case*

I have this code which is embedding a google map into a fluid width div. It is being cut off at the side, which according to my research is because I need to add google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') to prevent this from happening. The only problem is, I don't know where in my code it should go. Thanks in advance for all help :)

```js
function initMap() {
        // Styles a map in night mode.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 59.3367746, lng: 18.079787},
          zoom: 16,
          styles:  [
            {"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e9e9"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#333333"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}
            ]
        });
  // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
  var image = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/marker.svg';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.3367746, 18.079787),
    map: map,
    icon: image,
  });
      }
```

Comment: Which version of the API are you using?

Comment: The `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` was removed in version 3.32 of Maps JavaScript API. Google implemented new renderer and deprecated this event as stated in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/new-renderer

Answer (score 0):

Comment by xomena fixed the problem, I simply added &v=3.31 to the end of my API key URL.